# Runtime error in website

Tags: mysql, asp.net

While generating report in the website, I got runtime error. So, to solve this, I connected to the local phpmyadmin mysql database and debugged. I did not get any error. The report generated successfully. Then, I connected to the main database of the website and debugged. Even now I did not get any error. The report generated Successfully. Can anyone say me what may be the issue? I am using asp.net as front end.

EDIT:

```
gvWorkProcess.DataSource = null;
if (chbStatus.Checked)
{
     dTable = getConn.GetAdapterDatatable("SELECT  (select umName from usermaster where umCode=stResource) as Resource,  (select umName from usermaster where umCode=stAssign) as Assigned_To,  (select csname from customermaster where csCode=stCust)  as Customer,  (Select pjName from project where pjCode=stProject) as Project,  stName as Name,  stRemarks as Remarks,  stSev as Severity,  DATE_FORMAT(stEstFrom, '%d/%m/%Y') as Est_From,  DATE_FORMAT(stEstTo, '%d/%m/%Y') as Est_To, stEstHrs as Est_Hrs,  DATE_FORMAT(stActFrom, '%d/%m/%Y') as Act_From,  DATE_FORMAT(stActTo, '%d/%m/%Y') as Act_To,  stActHrs as Act_Hrs,  stStatus as Status FROM  subtaskmaster left join timesheet on tsTask=stCode WHERE  tsStatus=100 and (stResource = '" + cUser[nindex] + "' or 'ALL'='" + cUser[nindex] + "') and (stAssign= '" + cUsers[nindexs] + "' or 'ALL'='" + cUsers[nindexs] + "') AND stActTo >=  '" + cFDate + "' AND  stActTo <=  '" + cTDate + "' and stStatus='" + 100 + "' and (stProject!='" + cNoEst + "'  or 'ALL'='" + cNoEst + "')", Global.conStrDatabase);
}
else
{
     dTable = getConn.GetAdapterDatatable("SELECT  (select umName from usermaster where umCode=stResource) as Resource,  (select umName from usermaster where umCode=stAssign) as Assigned_To,  (select csname from customermaster where csCode=stCust)  as Customer,  (Select pjName from project where pjCode=stProject) as Project,  stName as Name,  stRemarks as Remarks,  stSev as Severity,  DATE_FORMAT(stEstFrom, '%d/%m/%Y') as Est_From,  DATE_FORMAT(stEstTo, '%d/%m/%Y') as Est_To, stEstHrs as Est_Hrs,  DATE_FORMAT(stActFrom, '%d/%m/%Y') as Act_From,  DATE_FORMAT(stActTo, '%d/%m/%Y') as Act_To,  stActHrs as Act_Hrs,  stStatus as Status FROM  subtaskmaster WHERE (stResource = '" + cUser[nindex] + "' or 'ALL'='" + cUser[nindex] + "') and (stAssign= '" + cUsers[nindexs] + "' or 'ALL'='" + cUsers[nindexs] + "') AND  stActTo >=  '" + cFDate + "' AND  stActTo <=  '" + cTDate + "' and (stProject!='" + cNoEst + "'  or 'ALL'='" + cNoEst + "')", Global.conStrDatabase);
}
dTabPrt = dTable;
gvWorkProcess.DataSource = dTable;
gvWorkProcess.DataBind();
```

In website, the report is successfully generating for second query. But not for first query.

Comment: Please post some code so that we can suggest try catch.

Comment: I have updated the post with code.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "server error in '/' application runtime error" is the message i am getting.

Comment: If you are still debuggimg, you can set the web.config <Custom Errors> tag to not show a "friendly message", instead the full message.  You can also, for live server, run Friendly=RemotelyOnly, and still get the full message when you test on the local server.  Lastly, I would display out the contents of the SQL script you are trying to run - into a textbox or label and see if the script is valid SQL.